# Formatear las fecha en MySQL/MariaDB con formato mexicano dia/mes/año

Tags: mysql, mariadb

¿Como puedo formatear todas mis fechas sin usar la función DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y')  en cada uno de mis select ?

Anteriormente lo podía hacer estableciendo la variable del sistema **date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'** y con eso me regresaba todas las fechas formateadas

Pero esa variable fue removida

Lo que necesito es que al hacer

```
CREATE TABLE pro_facturas (
  eCodFactura int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fhFechaRegistro datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (eCodFactura)
);

select fhFechaRegistro from pro_facturas;
```

Me regresa eso:

**[image: texto en negrita]**

Quiero que me regrese esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin necesidad de tener que aplicar la función DATE_FORMAT

```
select DATE_FORMAT(fhFechaRegistro,'%d/%m/%Y') fhFechaRegistro from pro_facturas
```

**Como les repito, esto lo podía hacer antes, simplemente modificando la variable del sistema date_format y datetime_format y ya con eso me regresaba todos mis campos tipo fecha formateados d/m/y**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: formato mexicano xD bueno si pones un ejemplo de la columna que deseas formatear!

Comment: no quiero formatear una campo en especifico, lo que quiero es que al hacer select, en un campo tipo fecha me lo regrese con el formato %d/%m/%Y

Comment: Si, anteriormente solo modifica la variable del sistema date_format  y con esos al hacer un select sobre cualquier campo fecha me lo regresaba con el formato que quería, pero esa variable del sistema desapareció, y ahora no se como hacerlo

Comment: @ManuelAlbertoGomezLozano, lo que buscas ya no se puede lograr modificando variables de sistema, dado que [las mismas fueron deprecadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_date_format) y no existen sustitutos/reemplazos. En otras palabras, para modificar el formato por defecto en que son devueltas es necesario aplicar una `función`

Comment: @ManuelAlbertoGomezLozano, fehacientemente no lo se, pero me inclino a pensar que fueron deprecadas para evitar confusiones y unificar formatos, como así también en favor de la utilización de funciones para lograr dicho objetivo. No, ya no existe variables para lograr esto.

Comment: Como bien dice @Marcos, la variable de sistema `date_format` que daba la posibilidad de cambiar el formato de fecha del sistema, fue removida a partir de MySQL 8.0.3, [puedes consultarlo aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_date_format). Esto no es una catástrofe, sino una decisión coherente. Un formato de fecha es una de las cosas más relativas que existen, porque dependen de miles de factores, por lo tanto, no tiene demasiado sentido configurar el sistema a un determinado formato. Los errores que pueden ocurrir son múltiples...

Comment: ... y es más costoso controlarlos que hacer lo que hay que hacer, que es aplicar el formato en el contexto, formateando **esa fecha** cuando la hayas traído de la base de datos. Además, aunque no tengo ninguna prueba a mano, alterar el funcionamiento normal del sistema suele tener su precio a nivel de rendimiento.